# Exception in external script not showing on console

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

I'm making a small library to be used on browser and came across (what I think of as) a strange behaviour of *throw*.

When I run this code:

```
var SomeClass = function() {};

SomeClass.prototype.error = function() {
    throw new Error('Error!');
};

var myInstance = new SomeClass();
myInstance.error();
```

it's just fine, SomeClass is defined internally and myInstance is initialized in the same script, and the exception is displayed on the browser's console. However:

```
// Code on a web page
var SomeClass = function() {};

SomeClass.prototype.error = function() {
    throw new Error('Error!');
};
```

```
// Initialize a SomeClass instance locally
$.getScript('http://127.0.0.1:5500/SomeClass.js')
.then(function() {
    var myInstance = new SomeClass();
    myInstance.error();
});
```

In this case nothing is shown on console. Why does this happen?

This can be prevented if we create an Error instance as a callback to console.error as in the following, but I don't know this is a good practice.

```
// Code on a web page
var SomeClass = function() {};

SomeClass.prototype.error = function() {
    throw console.error(new Error('Error!')); // console.error added
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your workaround you're not actually throwing an error, you're just calling `console.error()` explicitly.

Comment: What happens if you do `.then(function() { throw new Error('Error!'); })`. We should determine if this has anything to do with the class, or it's just related to throwing errors in `.then()`

Comment: Thanks, it was because the exception occurred in the then block. Using a catch function caught the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using a Promise (getScript). Inside a promise errors are throwed/pass to the catch function. So if you do like this it will work:

```
var SomeClass = function () {};

SomeClass.prototype.error = function () {
  throw new Error("Error!");
};

const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve();
  }, 300);
});

myPromise
  .then(() => {
    let some = new SomeClass();
    console.log("execute");
    some.error();
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("catch error");
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew throw doesn't work inside an asynchronous function but didn't know that also applies to then blocks. Using the catch function did the job.